# Oracle Trigger on insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, triggers

i have the following trigger in my DB, but I'm wondering how i could modify it to also decrement  the inventory. I have both values in this trigger, the order amount, and the inventory level, can't i just put a, update statement in the if clause? I'm not sure why this isn't working, it compiles fine.

```
        create or replace TRIGGER INVENTORY_AVAIL 
    Before INSERT
       ON THC_ORDER
       FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE
       v_quantity_diff number;
       v_onhand_quantity number;

    BEGIN
       -- TRIGGR ON THIS...
       --INSERT INTO THC_ORDER
       --( FK_ORDER_NO, FK_PROD_ID, QUANITY , COMPLETE_STATUS)
       --VALUES
       --( :NEW.FK_ORDER_NO, :NEW.FK_PROD_ID, :NEW.QUANITY , :NEW.COMPLETE_STATUS);
       SELECT INVENTORY_ONHAND INTO v_onhand_quantity
       FROM THC_INVENTORY 
       WHERE :new.fk_prod_id = THC_INVENTORY.FK_PROD_ID;

      IF( (v_onhand_quantity - :NEW.QUANTITY) >= 0)
      THEN
         INSERT INTO THC_ORDER ( FK_ORDER_NO, FK_PROD_ID, QUANTITY, COMPLETE_STATUS)
          VALUES ( :NEW.FK_ORDER_NO, :NEW.FK_PROD_ID, :NEW.QUANTITY , :NEW.COMPLETE_STATUS);

                 /* not sure if this should be a separate trigger... */
         UPDATE THC_INVENTORY
          SET INVENTORY_ONHAND = v_onhand_quantity - :NEW.QUANTITY;

      ELSE
      raise_application_error (-20001,'ERROR: QUANTITY ' || :NEW.QUANTITY 
           || ' EXCEEDS INVENTORY ONHAND [' || TO_CHAR(v_onhand_quantity) || ']' ); 
      END IF;

    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your trigger is not the update in other table(no particular problem for that) but the insert  in the_orders. It will cascade trigger until the inventory will be empty! So remove the insert into you trigger and it will work fine I hope.